# Understand the config file

Tags: prometheus

Im running an exporter that fetch metrics from kafka. Im a newbie in Prometheus, so trying to understand(searching right documents) to know the meaning of the exporter config file.

Here is my config:

```yaml
  #kafka.producer:type=producer-topic-metrics,client-id="{clientid}",topic="{topic}"", partition="{partition}"
  #kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id="{clientid}",topic="{topic}"", partition="{partition}"
  - pattern: kafka.(.+)<type=(.+)-metrics, client-id=(.+), topic=(.+), partition=(.+)><>(.+-total|compression-rate|.+-avg|.+-replica|.+-lag|.+-lead)
    name: kafka_$2_$6
    labels:
      clientId: "$3"
      topic: "$4"
      partition: "$5"
    help: "Kafka $1 JMX metric type $2"
    type: GAUGE
```

Basically where the flag `name` reflect in the Prometheus also what is that `$1, $2,$3` - where are they fetching the value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are defining a [recording rule](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/#recording-rules) in Prometheus. This rule creates a new metric with the `name: kafka_$2_$6` and labels with respective values for each: `clientId: "$3"`, `topic: "$4"`, `partition: "$5"`. The values are extracted from the `pattern` attribute.

I tried to paste your regex on an editor and it is not fully working. I can get until parameter `$5` but not the `$6`. Basically, you have the pattern

```
kafka.(.+)<type=(.+)-metrics,client-id=(.+),topic=(.+),partition=(.+)
```

and if you have the string :

```
kafka.producer<type=producer-topic-metrics,client-id=clientid,topic=topic_name,partition=partition_name
```

you can extract these values from it:

```
group 1: 6-14   producer
group 2: 20-34  producer-topic
group 3: 53-63  clientid
group 4: 70-82  topic_name
group 5: 93-109 partition_name
```

then it will be used on the following labels. For instance, the name of your metric is defined in `name: kafka_$2_$6` and it will become `name: kafka_producer-topic_{wharever_is_in_6}`. Check [here the interactive editor](https://regex101.com/r/NQTo6R/1).

Answer (score 1):

The `name` flag will be the metric name. If your kafka and prometheus instance are running, you can see the list of metrics in prometheus (it's in `localhost:9090/graph` for me).

As for the `$1`, it's the regex capturing group, so it's everything that's between brackets. You can see that the `clientId` is `$3`, which is the thirst capturing group.